# Transfer from external direct sum to internal direct sum

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum

Let $K$ be a $n$-dimensional vector subspace of $\mathbb R^N$. Then we have the surjective canonical homeomorphism $$f: \mathbb R^N \to \mathbb R^N/K, \quad x \mapsto x+K.$$

We have $\operatorname{ker} f = K$. By rank–nullity theorem, $\dim (\mathbb R^N/K) = N-n$. There exists $H \subseteq \mathbb R^N$ such that $\mathbb R^N/K \cong H$. This implies $H$ is a $(N-n)$-dimensional vector subspace of $\mathbb R^N$. Also, $\mathbb R^N  \cong (\mathbb R^N/K) \oplus_e K$.

I would like to ask if we have $\mathbb R^N = H \oplus_i K$.  Here $\oplus_e$ and $\oplus_i$ are the external and internal direct sums respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $H$ was chosen extremely generally, it's quite easy to arrange for this to fail to be an internal direct sum. In $\Bbb R^2$, for example, take $K=H=\{(x,0)\colon x\in\Bbb R\}\cong \Bbb R^1$.

Comment: Can we choose a $H$ such that $\mathbb R^N = H \oplus_i K$?

Comment: Certainly—just extend a basis $B$ for $K$ to a basis $C$ for $\Bbb R^N$, and let $H$ be the subspace spanned by $C\setminus B$.